# How to get a key of string enum in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I want to get the key from the **string enum** as a string.

```
enum myEnum {
   myFoo = "My Foo",
   myBar = "My Bar",
}
```

Then I need get `'myFoo'` from `myEnum.myFoo`

I have solved it like this but it seems like it can be much more simpler

```
function getKeyOfMyEnum(myVal: string): string {
    for (var enm in myEnum) {
        if (isValid(enm) && myEnum[enm] === myVal)
            return enm;
    }
    return ''  //I need the type not to be undefined

    function isValid(value: string): value is keyof typeof myEnum {
        return value in myEnum;
    }
}
```

and then

```
string str = getKeyOfMyEnum(myEnum.myFoo )   //str ==='myFoo'
```

Comment: This one does basically what I did, but it says ***there is no simple reverse mapping*** so probably that is the way to do that,